# php export html also with data

Tags: php, excel

I have the following code. It export the data to excel if do not add any html tag in page. When i add the html tag in the page.It also export the tag as well. I would like to export only data. I will have the drop down and text box for user input. Code are as under

```
<?php ?>
<html>
<head>
<h1> this is heading will display when page load</h1>
<head>
<body>
<p> user inputs </p>
<?PHP 

 *** sql connection string omit....***

 $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls"; 
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");

  $flag = false; 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT trandate,price FROM price") or die('Query failed!'); 
 while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) { 
 if(!$flag) {
 // display field/column names as first row 
 echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n"; 
 $flag = true; 
 } 
 echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
 } 

 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I don't see any question here?

Answer (score 2):

Error of excel gone after enter the following on client machine.

The easiest way to solve this problem, is to insert the following registry key. This will suppress the notification:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security]
“ExtensionHardening”=dword:00000000
```

The step-by-step instructions are as follows:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit.exe and press ENTER. This will open your Registry
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\12.0\EXCEL\SECURITY
3. Right click in the right window and choose New -> DWORD
4. In the Name field, type “ExtensionHardening“  (without the quotes)
5. Verify that the data has the value “0″

I advice the steps above to solve the problem, despite the fact that it is quick and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your data in file and give simple redirect

```
<?php ?>
<html>
<head>
<h1> this is heading will display when page load</h1>
<head>
<body>
<p> user inputs </p>
<?PHP 

 *** sql connection string omit....***

 $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls"; 
 $filedata = '';

  $flag = false; 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT trandate,price FROM price") or die('Query failed!'); 
 while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) { 
 if(!$flag) {
 // display field/column names as first row 
 $filedata .= implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n"; 
 $flag = true; 
 } 
 $filedata .= implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
 } 

 file_put_contents($filename, $filedata);

 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=' . $filename . '"';

 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank working... Error when i export it in xls 2007 i have to change any thing for make code work for excel 2007. If i do not want to save the file, on fly want to export is it possible.

Comment: you can make `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=generator.php?userinput=1&excel=2007">` and in `generator.php` do normally generation with `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel")` and without html tags

Comment: It mean i get input from user, then only command is $filename and this echo <meta > in main page pass varibale and then create second page  generator.php (which content all the code of my first code without html tags) and one post variable userinput. am i right? what is excel=2007 (how i read this in generat.php.

Comment: Not exactly. You pass all parameters given for this to generator.php in <meta>. For example, <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=generator.php?'.http_build_query($_GET).'">

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

Place the PHP code in another file called "excel.php"
Add this to the top of the file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excel.xls');
```

Then add a link from your existing file to this file:

```
<a href="excel.php">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. Only problem it is giving error.. "The file are trying to open "excel.xls" is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that files is not  corrupted is from a trusted source.." I think it is due to heard of excel.. Do you know the excel 2007 hearder

Comment: Yes you can't really fix that error unfortunately to my knowledge. I've just left it in there. Click okay and it'll load fine. If you find a way around that let me know. I suspect the only real way is to produce a proper excel file. If you want to go down that path, there are plenty of libraries around: http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=php+create+spreadsheet&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=

Answer (score 0):

try this script and that's working for me

```
<form action="itemexcel.php" method="post" 
onsubmit='$("#datatodisplay").val( $("<div>")
.append( $("#ReportTable").eq(0).clone() ).html() )'>

<table id="ReportTable" width="781" border="2"> Or <div id id="ReportTable">
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay"></td>
<td><input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel"></td>
</tr></table></div>

<input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay">
<input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel">
```

**itemexcel Page**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=guestexcel.xls');
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
?>
```